next.js image remotePatterns issue
This is my nextConfig setup. When working on localhost, the remotePatterns configuration in the Next.js Image Component works perfectly fine whether I use environment variables (env) or directly input the URL as a string. However, when I deploy the app to production, the Image Component fails to load the image if I'm using environment variables. If I replace the remotePatterns with a direct string in production, the images display correctly. I have also checked the server logs, and the environment variables seem to contain the correct values. What could be causing this issue?
// nextConfig 
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    env: {
        NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN,
    },
    async rewrites() {
        return {
            fallback: [
                {
                    source: "/:path*",
                    destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN}/:path*`,
                },
            ],
        };
    },
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: "https",
                hostname: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PLATFORM_HOSTNAME}`,
                port: "",
                pathname: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/image/**`,
            },
        ],
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

// partial file
export const BASE_PLATFORM_IMAGE_SRC = `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PLATFORM_HOSTNAME}${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/image/vendor`;

 <Image
    className="rounded-lg object-cover text-white"
    fill // fill container
    src={`${BASE_PLATFORM_IMAGE_SRC}/${id}/publicity/3`}
    alt={t(props.i18n)}
/>

I tried using env to configure remotePatterns, but it doesn't work correctly.

Did you check that wherever your production app is hosted also has your env variables?

Our sre is placed in docker and he said it is available.

You can just put the images in a public folder at root and access the images using a path and you wouldn't need to use the remote pattern no?

Because my image comes from another platform, he can upload the replacement image by himself, so I cannot use public as a static resource.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
